Split String based on condition in Snowflake/SQL
In a column if there is a string in the column col1 like 'abc_def', I can split and take the part like this
split(col1, '_')[0]
In the same column if there is another value like 'abc_def_xyz', I need to take 'abc_def'. Basically I need to exclude the last part.
What is the best way to achieve this?
I am unable to achieve this with split and regex_replace function

In a tabular format can you provide input VS output so that the ask is clear

Do you mean from 'abc_def_xyz' to 'abc_def'? If so, you can first split, then array_slice on the same and again convert the result to string using array_to_string. Please let me know if you need me to post the answer with complete query.

Hi @PriyasPaulzagade , Yes I need abc_def(edited my post). Also the complete query will help a lot. Thanks
